# Changing content of a string instance

Tags: python, string, pointers

Is there a way of changing the *content* of `str` instance in python?

I don't want to just create a new string because i need to pass the string instance as a parameter to another class which will operate with it. Then I need to change the content of the string.

I can't just create new method of the class so it reassigns the string because it's a `Widget` class of module `tkinter`.

I need this to change the color of the widgets. I know that there are methods such as `config` method that will do that for me, but when I have about a hundred widgets and then I need to change the color of all of them and every color is different it's very non-elegant, inconvinient to write *config line* for each one of that widgets and it is very hard to maintain.

I thought in this case it would be great to use a pointer but unfortunately there are no pointers in python. I even thought about creating some kind of class that would somehow `return` the `self.string` content instead of the instance identifier such as `<__main__.Spam object at 0x02F20390>`.

```
class String:
...     def __someprivatemethod__(self):
...             return "That returns string on call"
...
>>> spam = String()
>>> spam
<__main__.String object at 0x02F203F0>
>>> # now it should return the "That returns string on call
```

I don't want to use the `__call__` method though, because of the brackets `()` at the end. In this example i simply want to return `"That returns string on call"` string. Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but a few things that might be what you need: (1) use a [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) instead of a normal method; (2) use a [`tkinter.StringVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables); (3) use a list with one value in it as a sort of explicit "pointer".

Comment: Also, that `<__main__.Spam object at 0x02F20390>` can be changed by overriding the [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) special method. You can also separately override `__str__` to provide different "human-readable" and "programmer-readable" representations of same object (the way, e.g., the string `"abc"` looks like `abc` when you `print` it, but `'abc'` with quotes when you just evaluate it at the interpreter prompt).

Answer (score 0):

**No, you can't change string objects once they are created. String are** *immutable*

However, If I understand you right, what you want can be done with

```
class StringClass:
    def __someprivatemethod__(self):
        return "That returns string on call"
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__someprivatemethod__()
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self)
    def __add__(self, s):
        return '{}{}'.format(repr(self), s)

>>> a = StringClass()
>>> a
That returns string on call
>>> a + 'Strings'
>>>
That returns string on callStrings
```

Comment: But still when you do type `a + "Somestring"` instead of the last line you get an `TypeError`

Comment: If that's what you need, you need to implement `__add__` magic method. I've updated my answer

Comment: The `__repr__` method is called only in console, not in real code. I need in the *real code* to return the `str` when for example line `type(a)` line is executed. I need it to pass the "That returns some string" to the `type` function.

Comment: `type(a)` returns totally something else. If you call `type('somestring')` you get its `type`, not the value. `__repr__` is printed to console and also when you call `print variable`

Comment: If you want to return a string when calling `type` on object, you should look into metaclasses. But I really think what you are trying to achieve can be done in a simpler way.

Comment: Different actions make calls to different functions. If you can state exactly what the expected output you look for, we can try help you figure it out